# Automatic Timestamp based on another cell being filled

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, simpledateformat

I found a script on here to automatically populate a timestamp in one cell when content is typed in another. It works, BUT the time is never accurate. It gives the same time all day long.

Can anyone please tell me what I did wrong in my script?

My document https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NRNs6QUQ0K1m9mPH00zGUDiVxL8A1foTXxXIQ_XFjpA/edit?usp=sharing contains the following script:

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT-8";
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyy"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "Student Number";
  var timeStampColName = "Timestamp";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('SCAN LATE'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.    
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  //if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format)
    var d = new Date();
    var curTime = d.toLocaleTimeString()
    cell.setValue(date.toString() + " " + curTime );
  //}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`yyy` isn't a valid format for year. The valid formats are

- y
- yy
- yyyy

To get the current date-time, use

```
var timestamp = new Date();
```

To format timestamp to pass it to Google Sheets as text, use

```
var timezone = 'GMT-8';
var datetimeFormat = 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss';
var timestampT = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, timezone, datetimeFormat);
```

Usually the simplest way to pass a timestamp to Google Sheets is to pass a Date object and use the spreadsheet cell format feature to format the date value as required.

```
range.setValue(new Date());
```

References

- [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat)
- [formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format)